# pavucontrol: Connection to PulseAudio failed

Tags: pulseaudio, jack

After uninstalling JACK I lost my access to PulseAudio Volume Control. It says: 
[image: pavucontrol error]

I tried purging and reinstalling pulseaudio and pavucontrol and removing `~/.pulse-cookie` and `~/.pulse`.

Also, I tried setting *default-server* in `/etc/pulse/client.conf` to $PULSE_SERVER (taken from [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/pulse-client.conf)). It changed the message to

> Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait...

Obviously it doesn't seem to change. No terminal output.